# In my CV, where do I edit my current position and company?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs

This image bellow is my current CV.

[image: CV1]

The information that I want to change is my current position (Senior Software Engineer) and the Company's name (Agência Delucca).

When I click in the blue button "Edit", it doesn't show these fields. (as seen in the print bellow)

[image: cv in edition mode]

I tried going to my Stack Overflow profile and edit these information but it had no change in my CV (stackoverflow jobs), so I'm thinking it's a bug.

Answer (score 5):

This information is based on the entries in your experience section:

[image]

Since it shows that you currently work there, this is what we show at the top of your profile. To change the top add/edit your experience.

Comment: Note that it's also the top-ranked "current" entry which is used for the "who you would work with" section on a company page, if applicable; this was a recent change: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271648/company-page-who-you-will-work-with-job-title/271798#271798